Make API request from Oracle without certificate
I'm working with oracle 22. I created an API request using apex_web_service.make_rest_request to an https site and did not setup any wallet for it. The GET request went through successfully and response is valid.  I noticed that others have to setup wallet and add certificate to make API works. But I didn't do that and the API request still worked.
Do you know the reason why in my case it works? The site that I'm connecting to is a well-known site with a trusted certificate.
Thanks in advance for any explanation.

Most ikely because the database already had an acceptable cert. Having your db reach out and talk to untrusted sites is a really bad idea. If i were your dba I would want to have a chat.

And there's no oracle 22

You are using Oracle Database 23ai? Then there would be an easy explanation:
https://martincarstenbach.com/2023/09/27/using-the-operating-systems-certificate-store-instead-of-an-oracle-wallet-in-oracle-database-23c/

Sorry for wrong information. I'm using oracle database 21.7 at the moment. So the change in 23ai should not impact the behavior. I will create the wallet and add the certificate for the connection. What I don't understand here is my GET request still works without the certification?
